# Как сохранить данные перед удалением и восстановить при повторной установке приложения?

Tags: android, sqlite, резервное-копирование

Пишу приложение, при работе сохраняет данные в SQLite. Важно, чтобы перед удалением приложение сохраняло данные в облаке, а потом подтягивало их после установки. Реализовать нужно без регистраций.

Можно ли это сделать нативными средствами google (используя гугл аккаунт)? Если можно то как? Есть ли другие способы?

Comment: firebase real time database

Comment: Есть такой [Google Backup Service](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/backup.html) - нативный инструмент в андроид.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Да можно, погубил `Google Firebase` там есть `Real time data base`. Очень чёткая вещь. Вот ссылка на firebase https://firebase.google.com. Так же вот на документацию https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup.

После регистрации приложения в firebase тебе нужно выбрать realtime data base[image: Вот это]

Далее тебе нужно зайти в правила и поменять правила чтения (по желанию)[image: rules]

Удачи

Comment: У Firebase на бесплатном аккаунте есть ограничения и этот вариант может не подойти  из за ограничений на 100 подключений и\или объем хранимых данных в 1Гб - это стоит добавить в ответ, чтобы не было неожиданностей.

Comment: Этот вариант рассматривался, но это не защищенный вариант, по этой причине не подходит.

Comment: А что, вы хотели бесплатно?